# Best way to get pixel data from a JavaFX Canvas?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Is it possible to get ARGB pixel data from a `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas`? I am aware that `javafx.scene.image.Image` provides a `PixelReader` for performing this operation but I would like to get this data directly from the canvas if possible.

Answer (score 9):

I believe I've found a solution. Since `Canvas` extends `Node`, it inherits the `Node.snapshot()` method which saves the current state of the canvas to a `WritableImage`. Since `WritableImage` extends `Image`, I can get the `PixelReader` from the `WritableImage` and read the pixel data. This may not be the most optimal solution, but it works for my application.